# Long polling between javascript and revel golang server

Tags: jquery, ajax, go, long-polling, revel

I am trying to make an ajax calling (using jquery) and render the responses from the server as soon as they are arriving. In the server I send the different responses as soon as they are ready. If I make a request using curl I can see how they are going printing in screen response by response. But I can't do something similar using jquery ajax.

The code on the server is like this:

```
flusher, ok := app.Response.Out.(http.Flusher)
if !ok {
  panic("expected http.ResponseWriter to be an http.Flusher")
}

app.Response.Out.Header().Set("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
app.Response.Out.Header().Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
app.Response.Out.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
fmt.Fprintf(app.Response.Out, string(JsonOffers))
flusher.Flush()
```

This snippet of code is calling into a loop. `app.Response.Out` is a `http.ResponseWriter`.

The request I do, is a normal jquery.ajax function:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/ndc',
    type: "POST",
    data: ODRequest,
    success: function(offers){
      console.log( 'Offers', offers )
    },
    error: function(x,y,z){console.log("ERROR", x);}
  })
```

With this I get all the offers, but only when the last response is processed, and not one by one.

One thing more... (I don't know if it could be important) on the server console I can see this, in each request:

```
server.go:2161: http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
```

Comment: Data must be in key->value pair. Inside ajax function rename `data: ODRequest` to `data: { control: 'ODRequest'}` and update the necessary server side must be updated too. Also add `dataType: 'json'` to ajax function

Comment: Hi @AniketSahrawat ODRequest is a json object. And in the server I can get all the fields... so I think it is not the thing now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it looks like you want to `stream` the data.. you're able to see curl printing response by response because it is streaming. I'm not sure about the ajax way, but if it isn't a strong requirement, you could write the responses via a websocket.

Answer (score 0):

Please, describe the procedure more precisely, your application works the same way, like this?

Js script should send a request to the server, and when the response is received is again send a request.

```
var ajaxFunc = function () {
  // handle response and again call
  ajaxFunc();
};
```

When the server receives a request, it must run an loop for a certain time (may be 20-30 seconds), and send updates to the client

Comment: Hi @korchemkin. No... my app doesn't work in this way. The js must to do only one request (when a user clicks on a button). This request arrives to the server that has to build the response, and this response is made by three chunks. This chunks (by the internal processing) have a different delay between them, but the server throws each chunk as soon as it is built. And in the case you expose it seems that the js makes the ajax calling recursively.